# Patient patient

Tags: homonyms

The other day one of my students asked me an interesting question: why is *patient* as an adjective identical to *patient* as a noun? Isn't it because a patient has to be patient to recover (follow the doctor's advice etc.)?

According to [the Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/patient), the adjective "patient" means "pertaining to a medical patient". But the adjective seems to be older than the noun... So, is there a direct connection between the words? I know that they have the same French/Latin origin. But my question is more about the very concepts of being a medical patient and having patience.

Comment: According to [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/patient) they have the same origin. They both stem from the French _pacient_ and before that from the Latin _patientem_.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Unfortunately, I found nothing that would answer my question. I'm not sure it can be answered using commonly available references.

Comment: Which search engine did you use and what did you type into it? I tried "patient origin of word" and "patient etymology" (which means the same thing) and got lots of hits with good explanations both times.

Comment: @Enguroo I hope you've read the list of recommended commonly available sources; you can find this by searching Meta. The Online Etymology Dictionary is almost always the first place to check for word histories including semantic broadening.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I think I've found something. Thank you for your advice. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Enguroo Your answer below, as promised. Thanks for re-posing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/138821?rskey=cSezwj&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid), for the **verb** :

> to make patient' or 'to be patient'

gives references to both the French *pacient* and the Latin *patientem* which are present in English at about the same time, but originally with different spellings.

> 1551   R. Robinson tr. T. More Vtopia sig. Eiii   **Patient** iourself, good maister Freare (quod he)..and be not angry.
>
> 1561   T. Norton & T. Sackville Gorboduc iv. ii. F iij b   **Pacient** your grace, perhappes he liueth yet.

Later, the spellings converge.

---

For the **adjective** :

> Enduring pain, affliction, inconvenience, etc., calmly, without discontent or complaint; characterized by or showing such endurance.

the OED gives

> **c1350**   Apocalypse St. John: A Version (Harl. 874) (1961) 4 (MED)   His entent is to amonesten to be pacient, for þorouȝ þouȝt alle þe tribulaciouns..ben hard & stronge forto suffren.

The OED gives several references in the French spelling then it appears to merge with the Latin spelling with Shakespeare :

> **1600**   Shakespeare Merchant of Venice i. iii. 108   Manie a time..you haue rated me..Still haue I borne it with a patient shrug.

---

The OED also gives a somewhat different shade of meaning to the adjective :

> Able to wait calmly; quietly expectant; not hasty or impetuous.

and references this back to the Wycliffe bible of 1382, again with the French spelling :

> 1382 Bible (Wycliffite, E.V.) (Bodl. 959) (1965) Ecclus. vii. 9   Betere is a **pacient** man þan þe enhauncynge hymselue

---

They list yet another meaning

> **Undergoing the action of another**; passive; (also) achieved or acquired inwardly. Chiefly in contrast with active, agent. Obs.

and reference this to, first the French and then the Latin spelling :

> a1425   tr. Guy de Chauliac Grande Chirurgie (N.Y. Acad. Med.) f. 76v (MED)   Cause particler, **pacient**, or suffryng [L. Causa particularis patiens], was disposicioun of þe body as cachochimia, i. yuel chimez, & debilitacioun & opilacioun.
> a1522   G. Douglas tr. Virgil Æneid (1957) II. 22   The ayr and the fyr is actyve, and the watyr and the erth **patient.**

It is interesting to see the scope of the concept - first patience, then the acceptance of ministering from another, then the idea of a 'patient' emerging.

---

Then, the noun :

> A person receiving or (in later use) registered to receive medical treatment, esp. at a particular establishment or from a particular practitioner; a person staying in a hospital for medical treatment.

is also referenced with both spellings (French and Latin) :

> 1387-95   Chaucer Canterbury Tales Prol. 415   He kepte his **pacient** a ful greet deel In houres by his magik natureel.
>
> a1500   tr. Lanfranc Sci. Cirurgie (Wellcome) f.28 (MED)   If þe mater be mechill, the mater shall be þrest lytill and lytill, namely if þe pacient be febill.
>
> 1547   A. Borde Breuiary of Helthe i. Proheme f. iiii   Chierurgions ought..nat to be boystiouse aboute his pacientes but louyngly to comfort them.
>
> 1623   Shakespeare & J. Fletcher Henry VIII iii. ii. 41   He brings his Physicke After his **Patients** death

firstly with the French and then (again in Shakespeare) the Latin spellings.

---

It is interesting to see both the origins (French and Latin) come into English simultaneously, with, initially, their respective spellings. And also to see that slightly different meanings are being brought in as well.

I think it would be a rather large study to sort out the several subtleties of meaning, perhaps the several localised or dialectic shades of usage, and to track the merging of the two spellings.

But it is an interesting example of how English formed.

---

All references from [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/138821?rskey=cSezwj&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

Comment: @Enguroo My pleasure. Interesting question.